# Binomial coefficient in C

Tags: c

**Here you can find the problem I'm trying to solve:**

For integers n and k (0<=k<=n<1001) determine  (binomial coefficient).

Input

The first line of the standard input contains one integer t (t<1001) which is the number of test cases.

In each of the next t lines there are numbers n and k.

Output

For each test print (binomial coefficient).

Example:

```
Input
3
0 0
7 3
1000 2
Output:
1
35
499500
```

I can't seem to find anything wrong in my solution (other than it's written very poorly - I've started programming quite recently):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned long int t,n,k,binomial=1;
    unsigned long int number=1;

    for(scanf("%lu",&t);t>0;t--)
    {
        scanf("%lu%lu",&n,&k);
        if(k<(n/2)) k=n-k;
        for(binomial=1,number=1;n>k;k++)
        {
            binomial=binomial*(k+1)/number;
            number++;
        }
        printf("%lu\n",binomial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine for the example input, but the solution is judged via a problem site

(http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/BINOMIAL/english/)

and the solution is not accepted. I tried other inputs too and all of them gave back the right output. My question is: Is there a reason why this solution is invalid?

Comment: You should explain what is going wrong.

Comment: 1. Please post the problem here instead of sending us to an external link. 2. Post the complete code, right now we can't see things like variable types. 3. What is the input you tested, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: Also, when you say "I can't seem to find anything wrong", are you implying that there is something wrong? Does it work for you, but fails when you submit? In other words, your post simply states a fact ("I can't seem to find...") and doesn't pose any question.

Comment: The code presented does not produce the expected output

Comment: 0<=k<=n<1001. So check if your solution calculates 1000 choose 8 correctly (the answer is 24115080524699431125). This might give you some direction as to what is wrong with your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As 1000C500 is around 300 digits, it cant be stored in an unsigned long. In short, you need to start over and think of a better technique.

Comment: As you can see my solution is based on that idea. The idea being that a product of two consecutive integers is divisible by 2, a product of three consecutive integers is divisible by 3... and so on.

Comment: @user1870661 Where are you updating number ?

Comment: Sorry, now the code is as it should be. I changed the "licz++" to "number++". But I still cannot submit the answer.

Comment: What message is the judge giving you (WA, TLE, NZEC, SIGSEV) ?

Comment: The message is : Wrong Answer